# Beanstalk Getting Socket error 110: Connection timed out

Tags: php, tcp, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I am using Beanstalk server with Pheanstalk Connection in php application.

Previously it was fine, but suddenly it is getting error

```
Critical: Fatal. Socket error 110: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I have the same issue but happening once every few days. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem at your firewall, you should read the manual or config files of Beanstalk server to find out what port it's using and allow the used ports (default 11300) in your firewall where needed. After this you should never see this error again. If it's still not working: Please set the IP as well.